# Callbacks are not supported on Templatefield

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am working with a GridView and an ObjectDataSource with templatefield. I am implementing Sorting.

I have a checkbox field in grid view for select a row and set `autopostback=true`.

When i checked checkbox and postback , templatefield don't show. If

```
EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks = True;
```

I get exception:

> **NotSupportedException: Callbacks are not supported on TemplateField because some controls cannot update properly in a callback. Turn callbacks off on GridView.**

Answer (score 1):

From documentation.

> All columns in the Columns collection must support callbacks for this feature to work. If the Columns collection contains a column that does not support callbacks, such as TemplateField, a NotSupportedException exception is raised

Use this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.enablesortingandpagingcallbacks(v=vs.80).aspx) for details.